# Auto change page when selecting from dropdown

Tags: php, javascript

I have limited JavaScript knowledge and am trying to change a form so it autochanges when the drop down is selected without having to click a go button.

How would I amend the following code? There are 3 separate drop downs in there. I've tried inserting `onselect` in there but it didnt seem to work?

```
<select name="season">
<option value="0"><?= $txt_all ?></option>
<?php
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($get_seasons))
{
    if($data['SeasonID'] == $defaultseasonid)
        echo "<option value=\"$data[SeasonID]\" SELECTED>$data[SeasonName]</option>\n";
    else
        echo "<option value=\"$data[SeasonID]\">$data[SeasonName]</option>\n";
}
mysql_free_result($get_seasons);
?>
</select>
<select name="matchtype">
<option value="0"><?= $txt_all ?></option>
<?php
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($get_types))
{
    if($data['MatchTypeID'] == $defaultmatchtypeid)
        echo "<option value=\"$data[MatchTypeID]\" SELECTED>$data[MatchTypeName]</option>\n";
    else
        echo "<option value=\"$data[MatchTypeID]\">$data[MatchTypeName]</option>\n";
}
mysql_free_result($get_types);
?>
</select> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go"><td bgcolor="<?php echo $inside_c ?>" align="center">
&nbsp;Other Stats <br><select name="changeto">

<option value="1"><?= $txt_match_statistics ?></option>
<option value="2"><?= $txt_recordbook ?></option>
<option value="5"><?= $txt_opponent_list ?></option>
<option value="6"><?= $txt_this_day ?></option>

</select> <input type="submit" name="changepage" value="Go">
```

Comment: Change a page, meaning redirecting the page?

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you can listen your drop down list when it changes.

```
$('select').change(function(){
    // Do stuff
});
```

If you want to submit your form immediately after changing drop down value you can do this:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    $('form').submit();
});
```

In right context you can see example from here(and mess around with it!): http://jsfiddle.net/EB635/

Comment: Thank you for the response :) I'm still one the wiser though :( what would i need to do to the code above?

Comment: You need jQuery to run that code. Put this code inside your `<head></head>` tags: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` Wow! now you have jQuery! :)

After that add the code below just before closing `</head>` tag.
`<script>
$(function() {
 $('select').change(function(){
  $('form').submit();
 });
});
</script>`